# Problem with buildozer while converting kivy to apk

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

So I'm trying to convert my App to apk using Google colab but just got that error, and I quite don't understand this.

```
[INFO]:    Building python3 for armeabi-v7a
[WARNING]: lld not found, linking without it. Consider installing lld if linker errors occur.
[INFO]:    Activating flags for sqlite3
[INFO]:    Activating flags for libffi
[INFO]:    Activating flags for openssl
[INFO]:    Activating flags for android's zlib
[INFO]:    -> directory context /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build
[DEBUG]:   -> running configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no --without-ensurepip ac_cv_little_endian_double=yes ac_cv_header_sys_eventfd_h=no --prefix=/usr/local --exec-prefix=/usr/local --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --with-openssl=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/openssl/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/openssl1.1
[DEBUG]:    checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[DEBUG]:    checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
[DEBUG]:    configure: error: Cross compiling requires --with-build-python
Exception in thread background thread for pid 50826:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no --without-ensurepip ac_cv_little_endian_double=yes ac_cv_header_sys_eventfd_h=no --prefix=/usr/local --exec-prefix=/usr/local --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --with-openssl=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/openssl/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/openssl1.1

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
configure: error: Cross compiling requires --with-build-python
```

I've been trying to look for a solution but failed, and don't really know what to do.
That's the error that occurs. Can anyone explain how to handle this ?